# Intranet Connectivity through Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-internet

I have tried searching how to get access to Intranet access on Android Simulator,Though i found lot of articles but could not found a solution.

I am able to access internet when i configured the proxy in the imulator.
I am able to access Google.com and other internet stuff.
When i am trying to access Intranet portals from the browser in Emulator it is failing to load and saying unknown host.
When i give the IP of the portal in Emulator it says Access Denied.
But i am able to access that portal from my desktop.

If anyone have encountered this please let me know the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What port are you using for connection? It may be that your intranet only allows requests through port 80, which is what your desktop will be using (or any browser). It is almost impossible to tell if you don't have the details of your intranet connection. Why can you not access the internet?